# Concorde : « un mot girondin froid et blanc, apaisant, majestueux, un peu exsangue » ?

Tags: usage, étymologie, histoire, littérature, registre

> [...]
>  Oui. Car la sombre pierre oscillante des fées
>  Le salue ; il
>   vit calme et formidable, ayant
>  Avec la ronce et l'ombre et
>   l'éclair flamboyant
>  Et la trombe et l'hiver de farouches
>   concordes.
>  Armé d'un arc, vêtu de peaux, chaussé de cordes,
>   Au-dessus des lieux bas et pestilentiels,
>  Il court dans la nuée
>   et dans les arc-en-ciels.
>
> [ Victor Hugo, *Masferrer* ds. [*La Légende des siècles*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k9610049s/f246.image), Tome 4,
>   p.648, extrait présenté au TLFi. ]

C'est nous dit-on l'emploi *par analogie, rare et littéraire* de la [concorde](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/concorde), ce « [r]apport moral, situation qui existe entre des personnes ayant même disposition de cœur, d'esprit, et vivant en harmonie, éventuellement en collaborant à une œuvre commune » (TLFi) ; peut-être un terme d'un registre plus [soutenu](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/concorde/17958?q=concorde#17832) (Larousse). C'est [du 12](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/concorde)<sup>e</sup>, du latin [*concordia*](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=concordia) (TLFi ; et il y a une [histoire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concorde_(mythologie)) de déesse avec ça, des [lieux](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_de_la_Concorde_(Arx)) ([2](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_de_la_Concorde)) etc.)) ; de *concors* (*cum cor*), uni de coeur. De manière contemporaine on a la [*place de la Concorde*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Place_de_la_Concorde) en [France](https://www.geoportail.gouv.fr/carte?c=2.320201992988588,48.86552999837045&z=17&l0=ORTHOIMAGERY.ORTHOPHOTOS::GEOPORTAIL:OGC:WMTS(1)&permalink=yes) :

> Non, cette place [place de la Concorde] ne porte pas un nom usurpé :
>   il existe une concorde entre les Français. Les arbres des Tuileries,
>   eux, le savent, et les balustres, et ces anciens parapets d'où, si
>   souvent, se pencha notre jeunesse, aux retours de l'aube, sur la Seine
>   déserte. À leur insu, tous les *cœurs s'accordent* ici; [...]
>
> [ François [Mauriac](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Mauriac), *Journal du temps de l'occupation* (ds.
>   [*Oeuvres complètes*](https://books.google.com/books?id=lcc8AQAAIAAJ&q=%22pencha%20notre%20jeunesse%22&dq=%22pencha%20notre%20jeunesse%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y) ([2](https://books.google.ca/books?redir_esc=y&id=lcc8AQAAIAAJ&dq=%22tous%20les%20coeurs%20s%27accordent%20ici%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22Crucifixion%22))), p. 330, extrait présenté au TLFi ]

---

On introduit la citation de Mauriac à partir d'une citation de *Paul Morand* (1888-1976) :

> La concorde, ce beau mot tout neuf sous Louis XVI, (...) un mot
>   [girondin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gironde_(d%C3%A9partement)) froid et blanc, apaisant, majestueux, un peu exsangue, un peu cadavérique mais qui avait de la beauté ; [...]
>
> [ Paul Morand, [*Parfaite de Saligny*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sgw-AAAAIAAJ&q=%22un%20de%20ces%20mots%20comme%20Parfaite%20devait%20les%20aimer%22&dq=%22un%20de%20ces%20mots%20comme%20Parfaite%20devait%20les%20aimer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-guzVoMDRAhVo44MKHdGADhcQ6AEIHTAC), 1947, p. 200, extrait présenté au TLFi ]

Je ne connais vraiment ni l'auteur, ni l'oeuvre (que j'ai vu qualifiée de *parabole contre-révolutionnaire* : n'aide point à ma compréhension), et la référence à la nouveauté du mot sous Louis XVI alors qu'il est du 12<sup>e</sup> m'échappe complètement, tout comme celle au « mot girondin » et à ces caractéristiques...

- De quoi parle-t-il (Morand) avec ces adjectifs et la géographie et est-ce de portée générale ; qu'est-ce
  qu'on apprend sur l'emploi du mot, sur son origine, et sur la
  perception qu'on s'en fait ?
- Les emplois de *concorde* dans les citations de Victor Hugo et François Mauriac participent-ils
  des propriétés que Morand attribue à ce mot et si oui comment ?

Answer (score 1):

"Girondin" fait probablement référence aux Girondins pendant la révolution. Paul Morand, s'il est contre-révolutioniare, est peut-être sarcastique ici, et "la concorde" dont il parle pourrait être une égalité entre les Français, qui ne lui plait pas. Je crois que Morand est sarcastique, les adjectifs qu'il utilise lui appartiennent en propre et ne font que renforcer cette impression de sarcasme pour moi.

L'exemple de La Légende des siècles n'a rien a voir avec l'utilisation qu'en fait Morand. Dans le cas de Victor Hugo, "concorde" a le sens habituel pour moi, "harmonie". Quand a l'extrait de Mauriac, il serait le plus proche du sens le plus commun de "concorde" ("harmonie"), avec ses connotations en principe positives.

Comment: Merci ! Donc la [Gironde](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gironde_(R%C3%A9volution_fran%C3%A7aise)) des Girondins, et non le toponyme. Le sarcasme est possible ; c'est suivi de : "[...] _un de ces mots comme Parfaite devait les aimer. « La concorde... se répéta Tincé. Je n' attendrai pas que la concorde règne et que les Français s'embrassent ; je m' échapperai d'ici, j'irai demander à Parfaite de récompenser un si constant amour_". Je ne comprends pas l'ouverture des guillemets, mais on parle de cette _Parfaite_, rappelant la _parfaite concorde_. Est-ce positif et/ou altier que cette concorde ?

Comment: "Parfaite" est probablement le nom d'une personne - pour moi, tout cela sent le sarcasme, et rien de plus.